# Adding external legend to ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe and the contents of the dataframe look like this:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4
1   2013-08-01  1769.00 1769.00 1769
2   2013-09-01  1106.00 1106.00 1106
3   2013-10-01  1180.00 1180.00 1180
4   2013-11-01  1401.00 1401.00 1401
5   2013-12-01  1327.00 1327.00 1327
6   2014-01-01  1673.00 1673.00 1673
7   2014-02-01  1455.00 1455.00 1455
8   2014-03-01  1819.00 1819.00 1819
9   2014-04-01  1964.00 1964.00 1964
10  2014-05-01  2474.00 2474.00 2474
11  2014-06-01  2255.00 2255.00 2255
12  2014-07-01  2183.00 2183.00 2183
13  2014-08-01  2016.00 2016.00 2016
14  2014-09-01  2271.00 2271.00 2271
15  2014-10-01  238.80  118.80  0
16  2014-11-01  149.25  74.25   0
17  2014-12-01  159.20  79.20   0
18  2015-01-01  189.05  94.05   0
19  2015-02-01  179.10  89.10   0
20  2015-03-01  228.85  113.85  0
21  2015-04-01  199.00  99.00   0
22  2015-05-01  248.75  123.75  0
23  2015-06-01  268.65  133.65  0
24  2015-07-01  338.30  168.30  0
25  2015-08-01  308.45  153.45  0
26  2015-09-01  298.50  148.50  0
```

I am trying to plot the data contained in the variables `V2`, `V3` and `V4` against time contained in `V1`. I want the entries after row 14 to be in different color. I have coded the following:

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=data[1:14,],aes(x=V1, y=V2), color='blue', size=1.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data=data[15:26,],aes(x=V1, y=V2), color='red', size=1.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data=data[15:26,],aes(x=V1, y=V3), color='green', size=1.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data=data[15:26,],aes(x=V1, y=V4), color='yellow', size=3) + 
  xlab('Time') + ylab('Revenue')
p
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

I would like to add an external legend to the plot and I have been unable to do that.
Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not plotting V1 vs V3 and V4 for rows 1:14, You can use geom_text for adding extra information:

```
data = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(15713, 15714, 15715, 15716, 15717, 
16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 16075, 16076, 16077, 16078, 16079, 
16080, 16081, 16082, 16436, 16437, 16438, 16439, 16440, 16441, 
16442, 16443, 16444), class = "Date"), V2 = c(1769, 1106, 1180, 
1401, 1327, 1673, 1455, 1819, 1964, 2474, 2255, 2183, 2016, 2271, 
238.8, 149.25, 159.2, 189.05, 179.1, 228.85, 199, 248.75, 268.65, 
338.3, 308.45, 298.5), V3 = c(1769, 1106, 1180, 1401, 1327, 1673, 
1455, 1819, 1964, 2474, 2255, 2183, 2016, 2271, 118.8, 74.25, 
79.2, 94.05, 89.1, 113.85, 99, 123.75, 133.65, 168.3, 153.45, 
148.5), V4 = c(1769L, 1106L, 1180L, 1401L, 1327L, 1673L, 1455L, 
1819L, 1964L, 2474L, 2255L, 2183L, 2016L, 2271L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")


p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=data[1:14,],aes(x=V1, y=V2), color='blue', size=1.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data=data[15:26,],aes(x=V1, y=V2), color='red', size=1.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data=data[15:26,],aes(x=V1, y=V3), color='green', size=1.5)
p <- p + geom_line(data=data[15:26,],aes(x=V1, y=V4), color='yellow', size=3) + 
  xlab('Time') + ylab('Revenue')
p <- p+ geom_text(aes(x= as.Date("2014-06-01", format="%Y-%d-%m"),y=50,label="Your info"))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the following error when I add the above statement: Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only. This is weird because this statement has nothing to do with date. The code works well without the above statement.

Comment: I have modified my answer above. The label 'Your info' comes well. The dates on x-axis needs adjustment.